# Making Scrapy Application with py2exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy, py2exe

I'm attempting to package a Scrapy spider with a custom GUI into a windows executable using py2exe. The GUI calls the spider from an external script. This all works fine when run straight from the Python script. I am running into errors when packaging with py2exe. This is very similar to the issue [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22742163/cant-make-standalone-binary-scrapy-spider-with-cx-freeze), but with py2exe instead of cx_freeze. I have attempted to follow that post and package using cx_freeze, but I still receive the same errors. Below is the py2exe setup.py I am using:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

includes = ['scrapy', 'os', 'twisted']
excludes = ['_gtkagg', '_tkagg', 'bsddb', 'curses', 'email', 'pywin.debugger',
        'pywin.debugger.dbgcon', 'pywin.dialogs', 'tcl',
        'Tkconstants', 'Tkinter']
packages = []
dll_excludes = ['libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll', 'libgobject-2.0-0.dll', 'tcl84.dll',
            'tk84.dll']

setup(
    options = {"py2exe": {"compressed": 2, 
                      "optimize": 2,
                      "includes": ['lxml.etree', 'lxml._elementpath', 'gzip'],
                      "excludes": excludes,
                      "packages": packages,
                      "dll_excludes": dll_excludes,
                      "bundle_files": 3,
                      "dist_dir": "dist",
                      "xref": False,
                      "skip_archive": False,
                      "ascii": False,
                      "custom_boot_script": '',
                     }
          },
    windows=['ItemStatusChecker.py']
)
```

Everything compiles normally, but when running the exe file, I get the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ItemStatusChecker.py", line 92, in OnButtonClicked
    crawler = Crawler(settings)
  File "scrapy\crawler.pyo", line 20, in __init__
  File "scrapy\utils\misc.pyo", line 42, in load_object
ImportError: Error loading object 'scrapy.statscol.MemoryStatsCollector': No module named statscol
```

What can I do for py2exe in my setup.py to ensure that the complete packages are pulled in to my application and I can access all functions (similar to the solution found on the post linked above)?